# MSSQL Exporting tables with some columns blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I need to generate a csv from out sql as follows:

```
Class   Teacher    email     Student    email
3Sci    Mr A       a@c.com   James      James@s.com
                             Mary       Mary@s.com
                             Joseph     Joe@s.com
4Eng    Mr B       b@c.com   William    William@s.com
                             James      James@s.com
                             Mary       Mary@s.com
```

And so on.
I am able to with SQL get the following:

```
3Sci    Mr A       a@c.com   James      James@s.com
3Sci    Mr A       a@c.com   Mary       Mary@s.com
3Sci    Mr A       a@c.com   Joseph     Joe@s.com
4Eng    Mr B       b@c.com   William    William@s.com
4Eng    Mr B       b@c.com   James      James@s.com
4Eng    Mr B       b@c.com   Mary       Mary@s.com
```

My question is does anyone know how to remove those duplicates without removing the whole rows?  If I can do that then I will be able to export it all to a csv.  I know it doesn't make for a very good table structure but that is what a 3rd party requires of me.

Comment: How are you currently generating the csv file?

Comment: Which sql are you using? (sql server, mysql etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I recommend doing this in the application layer.  But you can dot this in SQL using window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
    )
select (case when seqnum = 1 then t.Class end) as class,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then t.Teacher end) as teacher,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then t.email end) as email,
       t.Student, t.email
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.Class, t.Teacher, t.email order by t.Student) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by t.Class, t.Teacher, t.email, seqnum;
```

Note the `order by` in the outer query.  This is very important.  SQL does not guarantee the ordering of the result set, unless you have an `order by`.  And, ordering is very important for interpreting the resulting file.

If `NULL` values do not output as blank, then use `else ''` to output empty strings.

Comment: What a neat solution to the issue.  Thanks very much.  That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use CTE's with rownumbers to clear values. Here is an example:

```
; WITH cteMain AS
(
    SELECT '1' AS A, 'r' AS B, 't' AS C
    UNION
    SELECT '1' AS A, 'r' AS B, 'a' AS C
    UNION
    SELECT '2' AS A, 'y' AS B, 'a' AS C
    UNION
    SELECT '2' AS A, 'i' AS B, 'u' AS C
),
cteGrouped AS
(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A, B, C) AS RowNumber
    FROM cteMain
),
cteOptimised AS
(
    SELECT 
        CASE ( SELECT G2.A FROM cteGrouped G2 WHERE G1.RowNumber > 1 AND G2.RowNumber = (G1.RowNumber-1) ) WHEN G1.A THEN '' ELSE G1.A END AS A,
        CASE ( SELECT G2.B FROM cteGrouped G2 WHERE G1.RowNumber > 1 AND G2.RowNumber = (G1.RowNumber-1) ) WHEN G1.B THEN '' ELSE G1.B END AS B,
        CASE ( SELECT G2.C FROM cteGrouped G2 WHERE G1.RowNumber > 1 AND G2.RowNumber = (G1.RowNumber-1) ) WHEN G1.C THEN '' ELSE G1.C END AS C
    FROM cteGrouped G1
)
SELECT *
FROM cteOptimised
```